# nested loop join - ordering of entries

Tags: sql, inner-join

If we join two tables using nested loop join algorithm with no condition (e.g., WHERE clause) like this:

```
for each row R1 in the outer table
    for each row R2 in the inner table
        if R1 joins with R2
            return (R1, R2)
```

Will the ordering of entries in the outer table always been "maintained" in the resulting table? In some real database systems, will any underlying optimization break the ordering?

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment below, let's assume the ordering is not guaranteed, but

If we specify `ORDER BY`, with the order that is the same as the outer table (e.g., the outer table is sorted by ids in descending order, then we put `ORDER BY R1.id DECS` in the query), can this be optimized in the way that joining is performed according to the order of the out table and no sorting will be needed? And how some real systems behave on this kind of query?

Comment: what lenguaje/db is this?

Comment: Usually real database systems do not guarantee the order of returned rows unless you specify `ORDER BY` clause. There may be several different physical methods to scan through the data and database engine is usually free to choose any method it thinks appropriate.

Comment: Many RDBMS's can multi-thread nested loop joins.  When the partitions are reassembled, the order is not preserved.  This is a specific example in which Vladimir's answer can be demonstrated.  That is, no ordering maintained.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the ordering of entries in the outer table always been "maintained" in the resulting table?

No - the results will be returned in whatever order is most efficient for the compiled query

> can this be optimized in the way that joining is performed according to the order of the out table and no sorting will be needed?

Joining is not done in any particular "order".  If you want to specify an order for the output (e.g. `ORDER BY R1.id DESC`) then the compiled query *may* order `R1` first *then* do the lookups, or it may decide that it's more efficient to do the lookups *then* order the results.  If you have an index on `R1.id` then most likely the lookups will be done in order, but it's not guaranteed.

Write your query to give the correct outputs, *then* look at optimization if the performance does not meet your requirements.